# How to know in which way UITableView is being scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Is there any way in which we can know if a `UITableView` is being scrolled in upward direction or downward direction?

Answer (score 44):

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y)
    {
        // Downward
    }
    else
    {
        // Upward
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

Comment: Hello there i need help to achieve this. where do you set self.lastContentOffset? thanks :)

Comment: Hi just define a property in your scroll delegate class. @property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint lastContentOffset;

Answer (score 29):

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    if (velocity.y > 0){
        NSLog(@"up");
    }
    if (velocity.y < 0){
        NSLog(@"down");
    }
}
```

Comment: AND if you want to make a homebrew pull to refresh (or other view offset relative behaviors), this method is where you'd tie into when detecting the scrollview's offset - NOT the `targetContentOffset ` (that's where the scroll would end up after animation): 
`if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<0){
// scroll is above 0,0 aka negative space where the refreshview would be
}`

Comment: Does "up" and "down" must be swapped?

Comment: @NikKovwhat do you mean?

Comment: On iOS 12, if the drag is really slow velocity.y will be 0, so you cannot determine the direction.

Answer (score 13):

Could we do like this?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

      if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView].y > 0) {
        // down
      } else {
        // up
      }

    }
```

Comment: This will send up or down depending on the initial touch, so if you will start at pt200, move up to pt100 and down to pt199, you will get Up state anyway

Comment: Perfect! This solves the problem of the UIScrollView bounce changing scroll direction.

Comment: This is not true, if you scroll downward lets say 100.0pt and 1.0pt upward, your code will trigger the downward part (translation.y will be 99.0)

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass, thus you can set yourself as the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and get scroll view delegate callbacks.

The argument for one of these delegate methods (`-scrollViewDidScroll:`) is the scroll view that did scroll, you can compare it to your table views to know which one it was that scrolled.

---

Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you wanted to know *which* table view is being scrolled (I missed the "way").

To know the direction you can keep the previous offset in a variable and see if the delta (current.y - previous.y) is positive (scrolling down) or negative (scrolling up).

Answer (score 1):

You can track the difference in content offset. Keep the old one in a member/static variable and check against the current. If the old value it's lower then the scrolling was directed downwards and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
  override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if targetContentOffset.memory.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            //println("Going up!")

        } else {
           // println("Going down!")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (yourTableView.isDragging || yourTableView.isDecelerating)
       {
                // your tableview is scrolled.
               // Add your code here
       }
}
```

Here you have to replace your tableview name instead of "yourTableView".

**yourTableView.isDragging** - It returns YES if user has started scrolling. this may require some time and or distance to move to initiate.

**yourTableView.isDecelerating** - It returns YES if user isn't dragging (touch up) but scroll view is still moving.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing `UIScrollView`'s delegate method in this way, it's graceful.

PS: `lastOffset` and `scrollingUpward` is property of ViewController.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    self.scrollingUpward = currentOffset.y > self.lastOffset.y;
    self.lastOffset = currentOffset;
}
```